# Increase all date_time or date columns by a certain interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Is there any way to increase all date_time or date columns in all the tables in a database by a certain interval (for e.g. 1 year)?

Is there any php script or SQL query to achieve the same?

Comment: No, you'd have to write something

Answer (score 0):

FOR SQL SERVER, YOU CAN DO THIS:
select dateadd(year,1,your_date_column)
from table;

FOR NETEZZA, YOU CAN DO THIS:
select add_months(your_date_column,12)
from table;

I guess MySQL should have the samiliar function. 
I am not quite familiar with PHP though.

But generally speaking, I think that's a very simple function for sql tools.

Comment: this will only change dates for a single table, but I want to do it for all the tables in one go

Comment: I know in sql server, it has information_schema.columns and so on views, I bet you can use this system and write one sql for all of your date type columns.